# My iPhone no longer shows up in organizer

Tags: xcode4.5, xcode5

I deleted the provisioning profile to fix this to no avail.

I connect and everything.

Itunes can detect my phone. I can't do the same. I wonder why.

This happens since I installed XCode 5 beta. I CAN access my iPhone from that Xcode 5 Beta.

Now I have uninstalled Xcode 5 Beta, upgrade my original Xcode to 5 and I still cannot see my iPhone.

My iPhone should show up in organizer when I plug it in right?

Comment: Which versions of iOS and Xcode do you use?

Comment: iOS 6.1, and Xcode 4.6

Comment: Try restarting the Mac and the iPhone.

Comment: Use a legit Apple cable! If you have installed iOS7 a lot of fake cables doesn't work anymore...

Comment: I can do this with xcode 5. In fact, I couldn't do this with my xcode 4.6 since I got that xcode 5 I think.

Comment: Why the downvote? The problem is DEFINETELY not on the cable. It works fine. It was still working fine with xcode 5 beta. It seems the xcode 5 beta "steal" the connection between iPhone and organizer

Answer (score 1):

As Vision says

Use a legit Apple cable!
If you have installed iOS7 a lot of fake cables doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I used the same cable all the time. I think it happens since I install xcode 5 beta

Comment: @JimThio but is it a legit Apple cable?

Comment: IT IS  a legit Apple cable. I mean, if the problem is in the cable then it wouldn't work from the beginning. It used to work. It still show up in iTunes. It still shows up in Xcode 5 beta before I install it. After I install uninstall xcode 5 beta and upgrade my original xcode to xcode 5 the iPhone no longer shows up on organizer anymore.